# Nodejs, trying to export a var to another file but the value doesnt change

Tags: javascript, node.js, export

im trying to export a var to another file in a nodejs application, i ve managed to export it, but the  result of the variable should change when a user logs in, does the export notice the change and export it again? If not how can i do it?

File im trying to export from, the arrow line is the var itself

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var url = require('url');
var userinfo ="aaa";

// User Api
router.get('/user/:userid', check_token, (req, res) => {
    var userid = req.params.userid;
    users.getById(userid)
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        userinfo=data; <--------------------------------------------------------------------
        res.jsonp(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).jsonp(err);
    });
})
var routeinfo;
module.exports= {routeinfo : router,
userinfo: userinfo}
```

file im tryng to export to

```
var use_test=require('../routes/api')

var userf = require('../routes/api').userinfo;
var socket_io = require('socket.io');
var io       = socket_io();
var socketio = {};
socketio.io  = io;
var users = [];



 io.on('connection', function(socket){

    console.log('A user connected');
    console.log(`Socket connected ${socket.id}`)    
    console.log(`User -> ${userf}`)
 });




module.exports = socketio;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing this is pretty unconventional to say the least.
The correct way making a `middleware` and use it for the `userinfo`, which is the standard way.

Some problems with this approach is, Your `socket.io` is dependant upon the user(or any auto ajax call) hitting the `user/:userid` route so for multiple user hitting the route, the `userinfo` will not be contained for that particular session. One user's userinfo will be shown for another user.

Think it in terms of session, a simplistic way would be using an object to hold the value in `userid: userInfo` format.

For the original problem, I think as you are using `var userinfo ="aaa";` a string, it is not changing the pointer.

Maybe, using a object you can use the data as it will be pointers.

```
const userinfo = {
   data: null
}

and then,

userinfo.data = data;
```

But I won't go into the details as this is not a good way to achieve what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank for the opinion and the arguments, i ll switch to the sessions method .